# Notes showing in Tomboy but not on Ubuntu One - can't delete

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy

I have the following problem with tomboy notes. There are some notes that I cannot delete. The delete button is greyed out. If I look on Ubuntu One, under notes, these notes do not show in the left pane but show under recent activity. eg "# (Untitled 10) was updated"

How can I delete these notes and clean up my tomboy app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have edited template notes as if they were regular notes.  Template notes are hidden from the main UI and cannot be deleted.  Ubuntu One used to show them (bug), which is probably how you got into this situation.

You should delete the .note files for the template notes that are bothering you.  lepe pointed out the note directory.  Just make sure to delete these files while Tomboy is not running.

FWIW, we are working on making template notes a little more obvious and a lot more flexible, as you're not the first person to run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your notes should be located at:

```
~/.local/share/tomboy/
```

or (older versions)

```
~/.tomboy/
```

Other way could be to purge "tomboy" and install it again.

Comment: Purging Tomboy will not affect your notes in any way (that would be like purging OpenOffice.org emptying ~/Documents).

Comment: @Sandy: Yes, you are right. Perhaps that was the reason to move them from .tomboy to .local...